# When is a new house created?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, game-of-thrones

In the Game of Thrones political power and military might seems to be mainly determined on a the house system (Lannister, Stark etc).

Under what circumstances is a house created?  Marriages seem to amalgamate households but not create new ones.

Do people simply lose interest in their families and start their own?  If so, where would they live - it was be unwise to give a new house a castle as it would create another potential enemy in the future and lose you a castle.

Comment: I think the politics of Westeros in Game of thrones operates in a pretty similar way to medieval Europe, and the fictional houses are created and destroyed in a similar manner to historic houses of European monarchies.

Answer (score 17):

There are plenty of examples of new houses being made in the world of A Song of Ice and Fire. Often after a peasant provides some great benefit to their liege they will be raised into the nobility and given a house sigil and name.

Examples include: Davos, the onion knight, who saved Stannis from a siege with a shipment of onions; Clegane who's sigil of dogs was created after his grandfather saved a Lanister from a Lion with his hunting dogs.

For a minor house to become a great house they generally have to be on the winning side in a civil war or conflict with the previous great house on the losing side.

Comment: Did Davos have his own house?  I recall him being knighted - or does that amount to the same thing?  When you say a minor house has to be on the winning side with the previous great house on the losing it sounds like there are a finite amount of great houses allowed - is that the case?

Comment: Being knighted and having your own sigil is essentially the same thing as having a house I think. The great houses are the ones who are designated power by the king over their domain, eg being Warden of the North.

Comment: Knights wouldn't have their own houses -- any knight can make a knight, but can't grant the title and land that are needed to found a noble house. Knights are not nobility, either in Westeros or in real life in the UK.

Comment: Arguably not in the UK but in Europe haven't knights been considered minor nobles since about 13c?

Comment: So are there a finite possible amount of great houses?  Or would the king just need to find somewhere currently untaken if he wanted to make another one?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, Davos had his own house - House Seaworth http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Seaworth

Comment: *sigh* I have no idea why I did not just look that up myself!!!!!  Thanks

Comment: I think any Knight with a title for land has a minor house. Otherwise they are a HedgeKnight.

Comment: For a knight to have a house he needs to have been granted lands along with his knighthood, in other words a landed knight.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have the passages to attest it right now. But IIRC, houses are created by the king/authority giving the title and land for a previously common citizen, pretty much the same as a knighthood. Generally this happens if the citizen has done a action that result in great benefit of his master.

House Clegane is a example of that:

> The first knight of House Clegane was kennelmaster at Casterly Rock until one autumn year when he saved Lord Tytos Lannister from a lioness and lost a leg and three dogs in the effort. As a reward, Lord Tytos gave him lands and a towerhouse and took his son as his squire. The three dogs on the Clegane sigil represent those that died saving Lord Tytos

[Taken from wiki](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Clegane)

Comment: So a house would be granted to someone who did not have one and would then spread (hopefully) when he got married etc?  Can house holds assimilate others via conquest?

Comment: @Stefan yes and yes; that's traditionally how noble houses come into being and then disappear, dating back to Medieval society and continuing on through today. (Queen Elizabeth II has granted peerage to a lot of people during her reign, thought at this point it is mostly symbolic and non-hereditary; I think the last hereditary peer in the UK was created in 1984, the Earl of Stockton).

Comment: @Stefan (BOOK 3 SPOILERS AHEAD) that's what the Boltons are trying to do. Supplant House Stark by assimilating them through marrying Ramsay to the (fake) Arya.